# Base 64 Encoding issue (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS)

Tags: java, android, spring, jackson, base64

On my Android App, I'm trying to encode an image to a Base64 String to send it to an API that handles it. It works correctly when encoding the file from AngularJS (web) and sending it, but still not finding a way to make it work with **Android**.

**Here is my code:**

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 if(image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS)) {
     return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP); // tried several flags ...
  } else {
     return null;
  }
```

where:

```
compressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
quality = 100;
// The variable image is a Bitmap Image
```

**And the error message :**

> Could not read document: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64
>   (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '\"' (code 0x22) in base64
>   content\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5d1a0f8e; line: 1,
>   column: 276951]

**Update**:
There are some images (strings) that are accepted and others no. But I can't figure out why ...

not accepted String : https://jsfiddle.net/dqpth401/

accepted String : https://jsfiddle.net/r8gLejsL/2/

I've been stuck with this issue and any hint/advice would be welcome !

Thanks

Comment: The error is not in the code that you're pasting here. This code is perfectly fine. As the error message says, there is probably some other code that is wrapping your string in quotes (which are not valid Base64), hence the problem. Maybe some sort of sanitization mechanism later on?

Comment: Nothing is added further to this code ... the string returned is the one sent to the API :(

Comment: There is no code that sends a string.

Comment: `Base64.encodeToString` is a method that returns a String actually. That same string goes to the body of the API call, making the issue appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mentions a double quote (`"`) at what is probably the end.
The data is correct and convertable to a smiling face.

Now that suggests that something else is wrong:

- Content-Length, minus-padding at the end, plus-to-space http conversion probably work (other data)
- Hence remains the component: HTML image tag or whatever is used.

In the tag there is some meta info text followed by base64

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ..."
```

Very speculative: a missing e in jpeg (correct) as opposed to image/jpg (incorrect).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since this is something done on Android (Java), then the problem might not come from any HTML element. I'm trying to explore some of the ideas you proposed.